# reauthenticating users after promote them

Tags: spring-security, spring-3

Hi have an app in Spring mvc 3 and Spring Security 3. Happens that i decide promote an user( I have a database with user,role and user_role tables), but when i add the new role to database comes the problem, how updating the principal authorities without logout the user? Looking for an answer i found this:

```
// update database with new role
//... you fill in this part

// update the current Authentication
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>  (auth.getAuthorities());
authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl('ROLE_NEWROLE'));
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordToken(auth.getPrincipal(),auth.getCredentials(),authorities)
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

Now, this approach looks good, but my question is, given that securitycontextholder retrieves the information concerned to the current user which calls him, how can I apply the code of above to each user in the system, from my admin account?
I am using my own authentication provider.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to implement the following strategy:

1. Keep a global registry of users whose roles have been modified.  This could be implemented using a `ConcurrentHashMap` (or a distributed cache if you have multiple app servers).
2. As soon as an admin changes the role of a user, push the user's (whose role has been changed) principal (email address, username, etc.) to this registry.
3. Write a filter that checks whether the current user's principal in the registry.  If the principal is in the registry, the filter refreshes the user's role and then removes the principal from the registry.  The rest of the request is then handled as usual.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea, the problem is that when you say 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth)
you are reffering to one user, what i need is authenticating many users.
Tnks

Comment: The default Spring Security implementation stores the authentication token in the HTTP session object.  Due to security reasons, it is not possible to access sessions other than one's own.  Therefore, in a standard environment it is not possible to access `all` or `many` users' authentication token together.  You can create a custom implementation of `SecurityContextRepository` to store the authentication token, in say, an expirable in-memory cache.  This will give you HTTP session semantics and also allow you to access all tokens whenever you need.

Comment: A sample implementation of `SecurityContextRepository` can be found [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-rest/blob/master/api/src/main/scala/org/example/api/security/EhcacheSecurityContextRepository.scala).  The code is in Scala but you can easily convert it to Java code.

Comment: If your application runs on multiple servers, you will need to use a distributed cache to emulate session replication provided by the container.

Comment: Thank you very much im researching this approach right now.